# Action Script: Does setting an object to null, automatically remove all attached event listeners?

Tags: actionscript-3

Lately I've found myself constantly writing removeEventListeners everywhere, which makes code quite messy. I know it's a best practice and such, but in general it has no sense. Garbage collector should handle such a simple task by itself, shouldn't it? Is it that hard to remove all listeners automatically when object is set to null?

So I just want to be sure if that's the case. Does setting an object to null, automatically remove all attached event listeners?

Any insight on this?

**UPDATE**: 
In my case scenario is like this - I create an object and attach bunch of event listeners to it, then after a while I need to re-initialize this object. Of course setting this object to null is much easier then unbinding every listener by hand. And on most part listeners are anonymous functions, which means that it's not possible without code refactoring. When I simply re-initialize a variable with *new* I do not get duplicate listeners and such, but I'm not sure that it's previous value, along with all the listeners gets garbage-collected. Is it?

Comment: Casalib is a good set of classes that will help you simplify garbage collection. Useful for when you have a ton of display objects.

Comment: +1 for casalib  - http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_display_CasaMovieClip.html  check out the removeChildrenAndDestroy() function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are not setting the object to null, but the pointer that refers to it.  It will not be picked up by the garbage collection unless it is not needed by any other parts of the program, which includes listeners.  You need to remove all the listeners yourself, but that should not stop you from finding a less messy way to do it - like a dedicated clearListeners method, or a helper class, etc.

Comment: I often try to implement an IDisposable interface for every class that i build. That forces me to take care of implementing  the code that will ease the garbage collection process.

Comment: usually, i generally call for the removal of all listeners with a public dispose() method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use weak reference when you assign the listeners and than the "nulling" should be enough .

Comment: This should work provided that you clean after your self and remove all references to the object. Also, in some situations, if you do not make an explicit reference to the object it would be garbage collected and introduce unexpected behavior.

Comment: Weak references are a parameter in the `addEventListener` function. For example, `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);`. The final parameter, `true` is the `useWeakReference` parameter. I always set it to true.

Comment: weak references are misleading!  i learned the hardway, but luckly Juan Pablo Califano posted a very informative explanation to a previous question of mine on garbage collection.  please read it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200211/actionscript-forced-garbage-collection-not-working-in-adl